# How does VSS (Volume Shadow Copy) handle locked files?

Tags: windows, backup, volume-shadow-copy

Take this (certainly simplified) description from the [HoboCopy tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hobocopy/):

> HoboCopy is a backup/copy tool. (...)
>   It uses the Volume
>   Shadow Service (VSS) to "snapshot" the
>   disk before copying. It then copies
>   from the snapshot rather than the
>   "live" disk.

Since Windows allows applications to fully lock files for read+write access I was wondering how [Volume Shadow Copy Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914%28WS.10%29.aspx) handles locked files. (Locked as in an application does not share any access to a file it has opened, thereby essentially preventing any xcopy style backup of said file.)

Since Windows apps do their fair amount of locking, is there any chance to ever get a consistent backup this way?

Answer (score 4):

Volume Snapshot Service (VSS) relies on application cooperation in order to get a data-consistent snapshot.  "Providers" register with the service and are called at the time of snapshot creation in order to create consistent disk images. Since this is a bit of work, the typical set of providers includes the registry and a number of databases.

Typical desktop applications don't participate.

So the answer to your question is something like: VSS creates copies of locked files and the writers of those files are responsible for making them consistent.

YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Shadow Copy creates a read-only snapshot of the filesystem exactly as it looked at that time, irrespective of any file locks. (They are usually intended to prevent programs from using a file that is being modified by another program; this is not an issue with VSS as you get a static copy.)